# Using Slax linux to Write to a host XP Machine's system32 directory

Tags: windows-xp, file-permissions

I am trying to place a shell32.dll file in my Windows XP's system32 directory. Since I can't boot up my xp due to an error because of the missing dll file, I booted up my machine on Slax linux from USB. Then trying to copy the dll file to system32 folder. I can write to other directories but not to system32 directory. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I assume it's NTFS encoded?

Does slax have NTFS write support?

I know http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/use-ubuntu-live-cd-to-backup-files-from-your-dead-windows-computer/ works if you are willing to try another option (I have no experience with slax but know Ubuntu works as I use it and have just written to my XP system32 to test it).

Comment: I should read before posting, clearly.  Didn't see the "works on other folders but not sys32"

Comment: @ZiG: NTFS write support is "NTFS-3G".